# Deactivate MFA protected accounts

Tags: account-security

Does it still make sense with multi factor protected accounts to deactivate them after a certain period of inactivity?

I'd say yes because the user himself probably doesn't remember that an account exists when they aren't using it.

In fact we've had several VPN systems before, during the rise, and after Covid was "established", all of which require cleanup.

I can already feel the "how dare you" look, even though it's proven they never used the old system anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Dormant accounts are usually ripe for the picking for attackers, so you generally make a risk-informed decision about when to sunset those accounts. And that decision might be different for every company. For example, I work in a field where no account should be deactivated, ever.

However, because you have MFA, you have an extra layer of protection. That's good, but it can also provide a false sense of security if it turns out that the particular MFA has a flaw or can be bypassed.

So, in the end, it's a risk-informed decision based on business need, costs, effort, and threats.